# batch command in cmd vs. batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dir

I want to print all the C files in a folder (including subfolders) without the path and with suffix `.o \` instead of `.c`.
So I found this command that works in cmd:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %a IN ('DIR /B /S *.c') DO @ECHO %~na.o \"
```

But when I create a bat file with this command only (one line) I get this output:
`~na.o was unexpected at this time`.

```
C:\temp>FOR /F "delims=" ~na.o \"
```

I undestand from the second line that it has problem with the variable `%a`.
How should i write the above command in a batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a batch file you need to use two `%`:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /B /S *.c') DO @ECHO %%~na.o \"
```